Why is ARP needed if already received router IP and MAC via DHCP?
A while ago I asked what were the minimum protocols needed to implement a network stack:
What is the smallest set of TCP/IP protocols required to implement TCP
I've implemented DHCP and started to implement ARP. My understanding of ARP is it provides the router IP/MAC if you only have the MAC/IP.
However, I already know the router IP and MAC because they were present in the DHCP ACK which allocated my host an IP address.
Do I still need to implement ARP?
It's trivial to implement but I just want to understand what any additional reasons are. Is it needed if my router changes?

You may know the router IP and MAC address but you don't know any other devices IP nor MAC in the same network.

@tkausl It's a problem if I want to connect to hosts on just the same network, or both same and remote?

The same network. All other packets will go through the standard gateway.
